# Gwt unable to find GWT modules after Upgrading Intellij from 2019.2 to 2019.3

Tags: intellij-idea, gwt, configuration

I was recently using GWT with no error, however after upgrading to Intellij 2019.3 it fails.

Every time I run the configuration shown below it says: "No GWT modules found in 'TopLifeWeb'"
Even though as can be seen, the gwt.xml files are still the same place.

in the box to choose a gwt module to load, there also used to appear the 3 modules ToplifeWeb, toplifewebfeature and toplifeweble10.

Does anyone know a fix so Intellij regonized the modules again?

[image]

Comment: If it's a Gradle based project, try to delete `.idea` directory and reimport the project from `build.gradle`. In case the issue persists, please [contact support](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/requests/new) with the sample project to reproduce attached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this I downgraded to 2019.2.4 and the shown configuration can now find GWT again